# Correct way to search multilingual location names i.e. Brazil or Brasil

Tags: php, mysql, search, location, geonames

What is the best way of returning results from a mysql database search where place names are entered in different languages? The case in question is the following:

Entries are made in a database with a location field. The location field uses google places autocomplete to attempt to ensure consistent and correctly spelled locations. However users can both enter and search the database for locations in multiple languages. An example problem case is that **Sao Paulo, Brazil** returns 4 results whereas **Sao Paulo, Brasil** returns 20 results. The correct behavior we need is that either spelling should return all 24 results.

The search query (using joomla syntax) is currently:

```
// Filter By buyer's destination //
    $destination = $jinput->get('destination', '', 'string');
    if($destination!=''){
         $destination = $db->Quote('%' . $db->escape($destination, true) . '%');
        $query->where('a.deliverydestination LIKE '.$destination.' AND a.status="Collecting Bids"');
        $query->order('a.created DESC');

    }
```

Comment: Using a [regexp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pattern-matching.html) with alternate spellings would be one option, if you can control the search criteria; or functions like [SOUNDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex)

Comment: Interesting. Could you perhaps provide an example of how to use soundex() in this case?

Comment: [example of a function using SOUNDEX() in a multi-word string](http://www.imranulhoque.com/mysql/mysql-function-soundex-match-multi-word-string/)

Comment: You nailed it. Thank you very much. For others - changing the query->where line with soundex() gives the desired results: $query->where('soundex(a.deliverydestination) LIKE soundex('.$destination.') AND a.status="Collecting Bids"');

Comment: @MarkBaker - if you provide this as an answer I will mark it correct.

Comment: This will work for 'Brazil' and (I suspect) almost nothing else.

Comment: @Strawberry Can you explain what you mean? It actually seems to work for all sorts of mispellings: Bwenos Ayres, Lundon, Sow powlo. What would you propose that might work better?

Comment: @Strawberry - Any particular reason ___why___ you think SOUNDEX() will only work for Brazil/Brasil and almost nothing else?